# Consider the following sequence:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursive-algorithms

$a_j = 4a_{j-1} - 4a_{j-2}$

$a_0=0;\ a_1 = 1$

> For all $j\geqslant2$, come up with a general formula for the term $a_j$. 
>   Use mathematical induction to prove your claim.

I have calculated the first few terms of this sequence, and determined from them that $a_j = j · 2^{j-1}$.

However, I am very bad at induction (some might even say weak at it) and would appreciate if someone could help me prove that this is in fact the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, since your linear recurrence relation uses $2$ smaller subscripts in the definition for $a_j$, you want to use [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) to prove that

$$a_j = j\left(2^{j-1}\right), \; j \ge 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

In this situation, you need to verify $2$ base cases. Although the question asks you prove \eqref{eq1A} holds for $j \ge 2$, it actually holds starting at $0$. As such, you can start there to first verify it works for $j = 0$ and $j = 1$. This is true since $0 = 0(2^{-1})$ and $1 = 1(2^{0})$, respectively.

Next, assume for some $k \ge 1$ that \eqref{eq1A} holds for *all* $j \le k$. For $j = k + 1$, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a_{k + 1} & = 4a_{k} - 4a_{k - 1} \\
& = 4k\left(2^{k-1}\right) - 4(k-1)\left(2^{k-2}\right) \\
& = 2k\left(2^{k}\right) - (k-1)\left(2^{k}\right) \\
& = 2^{k}(2k - (k - 1)) \\
& = (k+1)2^{k}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This shows \eqref{eq1A} also holds for $j = k + 1$. Thus, by strong induction, \eqref{eq1A} holds for all $j \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For
$$A_j=4(A_{i-1}+A_{j-2}),$$
let $A_j=x^j$ to get $x^2-4x+4=0 \implies x=2,2$ (repeated roots).
So the general solution of $A_j$ is given as
$$A_j=(aj+b)x^j=(aj+b)2^j$$
Using the given initial values we get $a=1/2,b=0$
Finally $A_j=j2^{j-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a_n-2a_{n-1}=2(a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2})$ and therefore by introducing a new sequence $b_n=a_n-2a_{n-1}$ you can obtain $b_n=2b_{n-1}$ and $b_1=1.$ This is exactly the geometric progression with first term $1$ and common ratio $2.$ Hence $b_n=2^{n-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Now, observe that $$a_n=(a_n-2a_{n-1})+2(a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2})+2^2(a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3})+\cdots+2^{n-1}(a_1-2a_0)$$ and, as we found this is equal to $$2^{n-1}+2.2^{n-2}+2^2.2^{n-3}+\cdots+2^{n-1}.2^0=n.2^{n-1}$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$